# Q: Using Grep to find a word that contains each of the vowels in the correct order

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to find out on how to use grep command to find the number of vowels in each word in the correct order in the word file on the root user. I've tried `grep -Ew "*[aeiou]*" words` But, it never gave me the number of how many such words are there.

Comment: @msp9011 sure, you want the file? The file is 'words' it's located in the root directory, and I'm trying to find the number of vowels in each word in the correct order in that file.

Comment: It's not clear what you want; is it something like `perl -nle 'my %k; $k{$_}++ for m/[aeiou]/g; print $_, map " $_:".($k{$_}+0), qw(a e i o u)' /usr/share/dict/words` ?

Comment: .. or `grep '.*a.*e.*i.*o.*u' /usr/share/dict/words`=> abstemious, adventitious, facetious, ..., sacrilegious?

Comment: @msp9011 Okay here it is but, couldn't ctrl c very quickly to stop it. 
berserker
berserks
Bersiamite
Bersil
bersim
berskin
berstel
Berstine
BERT
Bert
Berta
Bertasi
Bertat

Comment: @mosvy 2nd one yes, but, I'm trying to use `grep` on `words` to find a word that contains each of the vowels in the correct order. To find how many such words are there.  It's in `/root/words` I'll try that `grep '.*a.*e.*i.*o.*u' /usr/share/dict/words`

Comment: @Anonymous ,.... non of the string you provided having all vowels...can u cross check

Comment: @msp9011 I've tried mosvy's 2nd command and it came up with this.

Comment: abietineous
abstemious
abstemiously
abstemiousness
abstentious
acetabuliferous
acetarious
acheilous
acheirous
acleistous
actinopterygious
adenocarcinomatous
adjectitious
advectitious
adventitious
adventitiously
@msp9011 sorry, there's more but now I need to count how many vowels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **man**:

> -c, --count

Suppress normal output; instead, **print a count of matching** lines for each input file.